# Rendering issue after importing from Rhino

Tags: rendering, import

I have an issue rendering an object after importing it from Rhino. After I put a material to the object using nodes it **doesn't** appear on the object while it does on objects created with Blender. Why?

[image]

Comment: hello, maybe don't use capital letters. Your problem might be that you've not unwrapped your object, or it has another material assigned and you need to assign the new one. Maybe share your file here: https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Next time make sure your Caps Lock is off.